# redirectToRoute does not load the page but typing does

Tags: php, html, symfony

I'm starting with symfony and I can' quite find the right terms to ask the question, so the solution might be really simple or a duplicate, so bear with me.

When I type the URL in the browser like http://localhost:8000/foo/fooPage/ it works.

But when I try to do this after a form submission:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('/foo/fooPage/');
```

I get this error: Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/foo/fooPage/" as such route does not exist.

So what is the proper way of redirecting?

Comment: Post your routing and your controller action

Comment: @TRiNE answer is correct, that is the proper way to redirect. You probably want to figure out your route. Use: `php bin/console debug:router` to show all your routes. The `name` is normally what you use in your redirect.

Comment: Thanks @AlvinBunk your comment was actually the hint a needed.

Comment: Hi Eduardo. I posted my comment as an answer. If you want you can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to figure out your route.

Use:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

to show all your routes. The name is normally what you use in your redirect.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Identify what is route name

*Annotations:*

```
/**
 * @Route("/some", name="some_route")
 */
public function someAction()
```

*YAML:*

```
someRoute:
    path:      /some
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:some}
```

As above config, `/some` is route **path**. `some_route` is route **name**.

## 2. Check your routes

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

OR

```
php app/console debug:router
```

will display route details as follows.

```
route_name               METHOD       /path
```

## 3. Redirect can be done as a return from controller

```
// redirect to the "some_route" route.
return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route');

// do a permanent - 301 redirect
return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route', array(), 301);

// redirect to a route with parameters
return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route', array('param1' => 'hi'));

// get route path using route name
$url = $this->generateUrl('some_route');

// redirect using route path
return $this->redirect($url);

// relative route
return $this->redirect('/path');

// absolute route
return $this->redirect('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks, the name was indeed something else, the php bin/console debug:router showed: app_foo_page